# Translating results by day to results by week with excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

In my excel sheet I have an varying number of dates in column A with associated totals for each date in column B. The dates are somewhat random but I want to find the sum of the associated totals per week. I'm new to vba and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to calculate the totals per week.

The psudo code for what I'm thinking is:

```
buttonClicked()
   Dim sum As Integer, tempDate As Date, current As Date, i As Integer, j As Integer, match As Boolean

   sum = 0
   tempDate = Range("A1").Value
   current = tempDate

   For i = 1 To Rows.Count 

       for j = 0 to 7
          tempDate = addDate(d, i, tempDate)           
          If cell(i,1).Value = tempDate Then sum = sum + cell(i, 2).Value
              match = true
              Break
           End If
        Next j

       If match = true Then tempDate = current
       Else
          `next open space in column D is current
          current = tempDate
          `next open space in column E is sum
          sum = 0
   Next i
end
```

Please let me know if there's any better way to solve this problem other than iterating through the entire list and counting 7 days ahead. I should note that A1 is already assumed to be a sunday and I'm not sure how the commented out lines should be implemented. I would be very grateful for any advice at all.

Comment: would i be able to automate a pivot table through vba?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a series of 7 row sums from column B, then this formula using native worksheet functions should do.

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B, (ROW(1:1)-1)*7+1):INDEX(B:B, (ROW(1:1)-1)*7+7))
```

Fill down to catch successive week periods.

[image: Weekly subtotals]

If you can supply a starting date (e.g. `=MIN(A:A)`) and add 7 to it in successive rows, then the weekly starting date could be a reference point for a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5). In E9 as,

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A, ">="&D9,A:A, "<"&D9+7)
```

Fill down as necessary.

If a VBA solution is necessary, that logic can be brought into a VBA sub or function.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I needed a VBA solution because some of the days will be missing and won't always be each day. Is there a way to modify your solution to check for this?

Comment: No. If some days are missing then you are not even sure where to start and if the end date is 7 rows down or even if it is 7 days away. If you could be sure of anything, I would concentrate on a finite set of start dates. At least then you could use a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) to include all values with a matching date that is >= start date and <start date+7.

Comment: If a set of starting dates could be defined, these could be used as the reference points for weekly totals. See my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

In other column assign the corresponding `Year.WeekNumber` to each row using the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR(A1),".",TEXT(WEEKNUM(A1),"00"))
```

The totals per `Year.Week` can be obtained using a `SUMIF` formula or via a `PivotTable`. The `PivotTable` can be auto resize if you use a `Dynamic Range` as `DataSource`